# How to fetch the defaultContentLanguage setting in a template

Tags: variables, internationalization, default, hugo

I am using the static site generator [Hugo](https://gohugo.io).
I have a multilingual site with `en`, `de`, and `fr` as the available languages. The default language is `en` as I have configured in the `config.yaml` file:

```
defaultContentLanguage: "en"
```

I want the logo inside the navigation bar to redirect to the homepage or my site. However, by using the following snippet, when the current language is the default one (`en`), the the generated link is `localhost/en`.

```
<a class="navbar-item" href="/{{ $.Site.Language }}">
```

I want it to be `localhost` when the current language is the default one and `localhost/de` and `localhost/fr` respectfully for the other languages.

How can I access the `defaultContentLanguage` setting in order to do something like this?

```
<a class="navbar-item"
    href="/{{ if ne .Site.Language.Lang .Site.defaultContentLanguage }}{{ $.Site.Language }}{{ end }}">
```

The related issue I found is this one, but I didn't find an answer:
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-value-of-defaultcontentlanguage/9643

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, the solution is to do the following:

```
<a class="navbar-item" href="{{ .LanguagePrefix | absURL }}">
```

https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-fetch-the-defaultcontentlanguage-setting-in-a-template/12397